# Storing Large JSON Object as JSON or as String?

Tags: json, performance, mongodb

I have a large set of JSON docs which I am willing to store in a MongoDB.

However, given I am searching and retrieving only against few fields, I was wondering from performance-wise which way it would be better.

One option is to store the large object as JSON/BSON so the doc will look like:

```
{
    "key_1": "Value1",
    "key_2": "Value2",
    "external_data": {
        "large": {
            "data": [
                "comes",
                "here"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Or alternatively,

```
{
    "key_1": "Value1",
    "key_2": "Value2",
    "external_data": '{"large":{"data":["comes","here"]}}'
}
```

Comment: Or store it as minified JSON?

Comment: JSON _is_ a "string" - it's a serialization, just like XML. If you're concerned about performance, **measure.**

Comment: @MattBall Come on, don't wake him up from his nice dream! :P

Comment: @MattBall, that's correct, yet, I am not familiar with internal processes when data is being transformed from one format to another, i.e. BSON, JSON string, and for instance Python dict. My question is whether loading a BSON into a python dict with many levels will be bad or better.

Another aspect, if internally, Mongo will be better off storing data as "flat-string" rather than BSON object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that storing the data in BSON is both performance and space-efficient. And by that you "invest" in future: if you store the data as BSON now, then it'll be possible to db-query it later if such requirement appears.

But anyway, if your concern is performance - you do have to profile it in the production environment, there is no way to tell that "it'll be faster or not".

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question, so i took the trouble to check it.

Sort answer is no significant performance difference in writes

here is the code i used for test it using pymongo driver along the results:

```
    docdict=dict(zip (["key" + str(i) for i in range (1,101)],[ "a"*i for i in range(1,101)]))
    docstr=str(docdict)
    def addIdtoStr(s,id):return {'_id':id,'payload':s} 
    def addIdtoDict(d,id): d.update({'_id':id});return d
    cProfile.run("for i in range(0,100000):x=dbcl.client.tests.test2.insert(addIdtoDict(docdict,i),w=0,j=0)")
     **12301152 function calls (12301128 primitive calls) in 56.089 second**
    dbcl.client.tests.test2.remove({},multi= True)
    cProfile.run("for i in range(0,100000):x=dbcl.client.tests.test2.insert(addIdStr(docstr,i),w=0,j=0)")
     **12201194 function calls (12115631 primitive calls) in 54.665 seconds**
```

Comment: Your benchmark is, atm, language dependant. You will want to run the databse profiler on that if you want any hope of understanding which is faster.

Comment: Sure it is language and driver dependant, but the original poster mentioned using python and still it gives a fair idea on the execution speed and a look at mongo logs do confirm that, also the actual data stored is a factor as well as mongo configuration, so I would suggest bechmarking using actual data and driver of choise.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a BSON document store not a JSON one. MongoDB cannot directly query JSON.

This is a fundamental flaw in your idea here, if you wish to query anything in that doc in a performant manner that can use indexes etc you will want to store it as a BSON document and not as a JSON string in a BSON document.

However if you were to use:

```
{
    "key_1": "Value1",
    "key_2": "Value2",
    "external_data": '{"large":{"data":["comes","here"]}}'
}
```

And you would only ever need to query against `key_1` and `key_2` you could actually find that JSON is not only more space conservative here but also easier to store, being a string (so long as there is no index on that field).